# Setting RGB TIFF "zero" values to "NoData"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, setnull

I am having a problem with getting my Landsat 8 RGB (bands 2-7) `.tif` background values (very small number but not zero) set to null.  I have tried the following tools:

Raster Calculator (image 2)

Set Null (image 3)

I have also gone to (Windows / image analysis), selected one of the files, added a function, and computed the "NoData" values.  Ran the function, and I still get the same result shown in image 1.  I tried using the value as well in Set Null and the Raster Calculator, no luck.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a read of GDAL NearBlack https://gdal.org/programs/nearblack.html, it's specifically for this type of situation where an image has been JPEG or ECW compressed at some stage though it may not work for *float data type*, give it a shot and see if this utility fixes the raster otherwise you may need to separate the bands with an arcpy.sa.Con and stack the bands back up again. BTW *packbits* is a horrible compression type for continuous rasters, consider Deflate or LZW (LZMA) compression instead.

Comment: How do I exactly use this?  Am I supposed to download GDAL or is this a tool I can upload into software programs such as Arcmap or ERDAS?

Comment: Downloading GDAL and using the shell is the easiest way *if* you're comfortable with CMD, if a command shell is something you'd rather not use then you would be better served by installing the latest version of QGIS and run near black from that GUI https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/nearblack.html.

Comment: I have not had any experience with a command shell, so I will opt to using the QGIS.  Plus I've been working on installing GDAL for the past hour and haven't had any luck.  I'll give QGIS a go and let you know if I run into any issues.

Comment: If you're on windows I recommend the GISInternals binary package https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php but understand your reticence with the antiquated CMD interface. From the same site you can install the python bindings which will play nice with your ArcGIS python install - as long as you get the correct bindings for your version of ArcGIS. This thread from GeoNet might be interesting for you https://community.esri.com/thread/47189

Comment: I installed both the python and GDAL, tested to make sure that my computer had it by running `gdalinfo --version` in my `cmd`, tried importing it into arcmap, but get an error that others have come across "DLL load failed".  But this should be a different question thread.

Comment: After browsing through my values for the RGB bands, I don't think that the nearblack tool will work because of the `number` parameter.  The data pixels and "NoData" pixels are to close together that the `number` parameter would be identifying the data pixels as being black.

Comment: I will try and separate each band and run the setnull tool for each band.

Comment: Then use Composite Bands http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/composite-bands.htm to bring the bands back together after the null is set. The syntax for importing gdal is **from osgeo import gdal**, using import gdal will return a DLL error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96025/discussion-between-zman3-and-michael-stimson).

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem is that the band values somehow got converted to a signed float, so you have a value that is near zero but not actually zero (or something similar).  It should resolve if you use the [copy raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm) tool in an ESRI environment and output an unsigned integer and specify zero as the no data value. I'm not sure at this point if you can run it on the entire image or if you must run it on individual bands and reassemble the bands as an image.

Comment: Getting it out of 32-bit float and back to integer will also improve processing speed and make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I ended up changing the band to integer using the `int` tool.  I don't think I could change the whole raster image because each band had a different "NoData" value.  So I had to separate by each band.